# i want to sum three fields which is get through database

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

page.ts

```
 price = 300,residential_package = 120, accompany = 1335;
 this.delegates_total =   this.price + this.residential_package + this.accompany;
```

`result shows 3001201335`

I want to add these fields value but it doesn't give me correct result please tell me where m going wrong and thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Number()` to convert to number and then use `+`;

Or you can use `+` to convert to number like `+this.price`;

```
price = 300,residential_package = 120, accompany = 1335;
this.delegates_total =   Number(this.price) + Number(this.residential_package) + Number(this.accompany);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case you are concatenate 3 strings
declare your fields with type

```
price:number=300
residential_package:number=120
accompany:number=1335
```